# In call back Function getting state error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, setstate

Initially I have state variable `url: ''`

```
let data = this.state.content;
    ContractAction._generatePDF(data, function(data){
        let filename = data.filename;
        let accesstoken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        this.setState({url : "http://172.104.16.14:1082/contracts/downloadpdf?filename=" + filename + "&access_token=" +accesstoken });

    });
```

And after API call, In callback I am trying to set the url state to the url given
but it is not updating

I am facing an error of State `Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`.

I want the url state to be changed to `http://172.104.16.14:1082/contracts/downloadpdf?filename=" + filename + "&access_token=" +accesstoken`

Comment: can you show the full code because with this code, you should get another error message "Cannot read property **setState** of undefined".

Comment: full code in the sense, what else you need I am calling API in that i am setting state url with the URL in the http://172.104.16.14:1082 etc...

Comment: the function in which you are executing this code, and how you are calling that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `this` has scope problem.

The reason why you get `setState of undefined` because `this` is undefined inside the callback. As it is currently pointing to the instance of callback not the whole class itself. You should better use [Arrow functions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html) that takes care of such matters -

> - You don't need to keep typing function
> - It lexically captures the the meaning of this
> - It lexically captures the meaning of arguments

do this

```
ContractAction._generatePDF(data, (data) => {
        let filename = data.filename;
        let accesstoken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        this.setState({url : "http://172.104.16.14:1082/contracts/downloadpdf?filename=" + filename + "&access_token=" +accesstoken });
    });
```

or just define it as scope variable

```
let data = this.state.content;
let scope = this;
```

and use

```
scope.setState({url : "http://172.104.16.14:1082/contracts/downloadpdf?filename=" + filename + "&access_token=" +accesstoken });
```

Comment: May I know what is the difference Both are similar right but previous is not working this is working

Comment: @user9883888, If you note I used `(data) => {` instead of `function(data)` here.
This is an `arrow/lambda` function in typescript. See updated answer and you will get idea what I was talking about.